# Displaying a blob image in a jsp page using Spring MVC 3

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a class with (amongst others) the field picture which is retreived from the database:

```
public class Person {
  String name;
  Blob picture;
}
```

So then I haven a controller where I add the person object to the model

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/online", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getCurrentUser(Model model) {
  Person person = getMyPerson()
  model.addAttribute("person", person);
  return "online";
}
```

And finally I have a .jsp page to display the user:

```
<html>
  <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
   ..some tags

   Persons name: ${person.name}
   Persons picture: ?your_answer_here? 
</html>
```

So the question (obviously) is how do I display the blob field as an image? I have tried and failed with . I really don't want to perform a new query to the database, I just want to display the image I already have ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP does not allow this directly. Each image needs to be a separate request to a separate URL. So you will need a controller/servlet that accepts the user id as parameter and writes the blob to the response stream (and sets the `Content-Type` header appropriately - image/jpeg, image/png, etc)

Comment: Thank you! Implemented a new controller for outputting the image